# C# beginner - how to retrieve data with specified account?

Tags: c#, mysql

HI~ I have a question about how to retrieve data from specific account..
For example, The have 4 bug report exists on the database

2 bugs report are assigned to developer a, another 2 bugs report are assigned to developer b.

If I log-in as developer a, I can only view the 2 bugs that assigned to me.
how can I set the code?

(PS: thx for many answers with pointed out that my coding is having risk with SQL injection, I will edit it after finishing my assignment. :))

here is my coding:

```
 private void bug_view_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Visible = true;
        bug_info_panel.Visible = true;
        string constring = "datasource=localhost;username=root;password=";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand("select * from bug.bug where Assigned = '';", conDataBase);

        try
        {
            dataGridView1.Visible = true;
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
            DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dbdataset);
            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

            bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
            sda.Update(dbdataset);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

And here is my login form coding`enter code here`:

```
 try
        {
            bool IsAdminUser = false;
            bool IsDeveloper = false;
            string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;username=root;password=";
            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
            MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from logintable.account where id='" + this.username_txt.Text + "' and password='" + this.password_txt.Text + "' ;", myConn);

            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            myConn.Open();
            myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                count = count + 1;
                IsAdminUser = myReader["permissions"].ToString().Equals("Admin");
                IsDeveloper = myReader["permissions"].ToString().Equals("Developer");
            }

            if (count == 1 && IsDeveloper == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You are logged in as Developer ");
                this.Hide();
                DeveloperForm developform = new DeveloperForm();
                developform.ShowDialog();
            }

            else if (count == 1 && IsAdminUser == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You are logged in as administrator ");
                this.Hide();
                AdminForm adminForm = new AdminForm();
                adminForm.ShowDialog();
            }

            else if (count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You are logged in");
                this.Hide();
                UserForm userform = new UserForm();
                userform.ShowDialog();
            }

            else
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is not correct ..Please try again");
            myConn.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Never use string concatenation to build SQL: you leave yourself open to SQL injection attacks. Parameters are *easier* as you don't need to think about encoding values for the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see the you are not using the recommended authentication method.
Anyways, you can achieve what you want by using Application/Session variables.
After the User is logged in, create a Application/Session variable and store User's Id in that like this:

```
Application["user_id"]=myReader["Id"];
```

or

```
Session["user_id"]=myReader["Id"];
```

Then you can use this value for fetching Bug report like

```
MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand("select * from bug.bug where Assigned = @user;", conDataBase);
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user",Application["user_id"])
```

Hope this helps